How do I connect both a PC and a laptop to 2 monitors?
How do I streamline my setup so that I can have both my PC and my laptop connect to both monitors at the same time? I currently am only using the Monitor 1 hdmi/dp, but my laptop only has one HDMI output, my second monitor is UPERFECT True 4K Portable Monitor with minihdmi/usb-c, My goal is to not have to keep switching cables around.
can you suggest specific hardware, and possibly also make it so I can switch smoothly between the two devices.
Between USBs, hubs, docks, and KVM switches, I have completely confused myself.

You might search for HDMI splitters/combiners -- but this is not the site for hardware recommendation. Try https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

You can search for kvm switch 2 monitors hdmi for a device to handle switching between PC/laptop. Depending on your laptop specs, you might need a dock or something to handle outputting to both monitors. If both computers have USB-C outputs, you could do both functions with one (expensive) device

As a completely different option you might want to consider a software solution: Synergy.
https://symless.com/synergy
It allows you to have one monitor connected to each computer, with only one keyboard and mouse. When you move the mouse off one screen it appears on the other computer and you can cut and paste (text) between them.
It's a different workflow (using two computers at once) instead of switching between them, but I found it extremely productive once I got was used to it.
I also setup a network share between the computers to move files between them.
There is a company that charges for Synergy (but they have a free trial).
And it's based on an open source project, so if you are willing to do the work you can still compile it yourself for free.
